# Unexpected result when subtracting two floats defined as constants

Tags: objective-c, floating-point

I'm trying to adjust frames. I have two constants defined as floats - `viewTotalHeightExpanded` and `viewTotalHeight`. I'm subtracting the two to get `differenceY`.

```
  CGFloat differenceY = viewTotalHeightExpanded - viewTotalHeight;
  NSLog(@"viewTotalHeightExpanded = %f", viewTotalHeightExpanded);
  NSLog(@"viewTotalHeight = %f", viewTotalHeight);
  NSLog(@"differenceY = %f", differenceY);
```

The log reads:

```
2013-08-24 12:30:48.305 WS[25737:c07] viewTotalHeightExpanded = 406.000000
2013-08-24 12:30:48.305 WS[25737:c07] viewTotalHeight = 366.000000
2013-08-24 12:30:48.306 WS[25737:c07] differenceY = 680.000000
```

Why is `differenceY` not 40?

EDIT

This is how `viewTotalHeight` and `viewTotalHeightExpanded` are defined:

```
#define likeBarHeight 20.0f
#define viewTotalHeight likeBarY+likeBarHeight+sortBarHeight
```

All the other chained constants such as `likeBarY` and `sortBarHeight` are defined as floats similar to `likeBarHeight`.

Comment: Are viewTotalHeightExpanded and viewTotalHeight both `CGFloat`?

Comment: @RobNapier I included the code for those above. They're defined as regular floats, and I was wondering if the conversion to CGFloats was an issue, but didn't think so since the log shows their values as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you're doing:

```
CGFloat differenceY = viewTotalHeightExpanded - viewTotalHeight;
```

which because viewTotalHeight  is likeBarY+likeBarHeight+sortBarHeight translates to

```
CGFloat differenceY = viewTotalHeightExpanded -likeBarY+likeBarHeight+sortBarHeight
```

So try this:

```
 CGFloat differenceY = (viewTotalHeightExpanded) - (viewTotalHeight);
```

Or maybe even better to make viewTotalHeight reusable without parentheses

```
#define viewTotalHeight (likeBarY+likeBarHeight+sortBarHeight)
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Or just use a constant rather than #define. When you include the pre-processor, you create a lot of unnecessary complication.

Comment: @RobNapier +1 Use of #define both introduces bugs, and makes them hard to find. The code the programmer sees is not the code the body of the compiler sees.